# How to test navigation flow in Spring test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test

I have an web application. It requires user to login first, then navigate through a few webpages sequentially. During this navigation flow, session attributes will be used to carry forward necessary information.

I am currently using Spring test - MockMVC to test it.

I know that a MockMVC statement can `perform` one action at a time, then assert for some result. e.g. `mockMvc.perform(post('/login')./*set username and password*/).andExpect(status().isOk())`.

---

**Question 1**: If I need to perform several actions sequentially, how to do this with MockMvc? I am looking for something like :
`mockMvc.perform(/*login*/)
.perform(/*go to first page*/)
.perform(/*go to second page*/)`

**Question 2**: If chaining `perform` is not possible, is there any way to keep a session information across several separate `perform` actions? I am looking for something like: 
`MockHttpServletSession session;
mockMvc.perform(/*login*/).saveSession(session);
mockMvc.loadSession(session).perform(/*go to first page*/).saveSession(session);
mockMvc.loadSession(session).perform(/*go to second page*/);`

Comment: In my experience, I've only used MockMVC when testing controllers in isolation.. It sounds more like you're trying to do an integration test? If that's the case, why don't you use a proper integration test framework for hitting your pages like RestAssured?